# Java substring is dropping first character if zero

Tags: java

I am using the substring function in Java and what I am finding is if the first character in the substring is a zero, it is dropped from the new string.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is the code I am having issues with:

```
ccode = actnum.substring(1,2);
```

Both ccode and actnum are defined as strings.  If more code is needed, please advise.

Comment: Post your code. Without it, everyone is guessing what you might be doing wrong. (It's doubtful it's a bug in Java's substring, because others would surely have reported it by now.)

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I tell the difference?  The actnum (which can contain letters) can be something like 03KL352 and is entered into a JSP.

Comment: As Chris said, a String uses a zero index, so `ccode = actnum.substring(1,2);` is going to return you the second and third characters of the actnum. So for "03KL352"  you're going to get "3K"; the first character is going to be dropped no matter what it is.

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot that it starts with index 0.  That solves my problem.

Back to your other question, how do I know if I'm using ascii zero or 0x00?  Sorry for the remedial questions.

Comment: Based on sylvarking's answer below, I must correct previous comment.  The first index is inclusive, but the second index is _exclusive_.  So for "03KL352" substring(1,2) is going to give you "3", not "3K".  API reference: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Answer (score 14):

The `String.substring()` methods do not examine the content of the substring, so what you are describing is likely a bug in your code. You can post the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem if you'd like some help troubleshooting.

---

Given the code and information given in the update and comments, this is what I'd expect:

```
String actnum = "03KL352"; /* Maybe actnum is actually entered via a JSP. */
System.out.println(actnum); /* Prints 03KL352 */
String ccode = actnum.substring(1,2); /* Assign characters [1,2) to ccode. */
System.out.println(ccode); /* Prints 3 */
```

Remember, Java's string indexes are zero-based. The first character is at index 0, the next at index 1. Also, the `substring` method takes two character indexes; the first is *included* in the new substring, the second is *not*—it is the index of the character after the last character in the new substring. So, the length of the new substring is `end - start`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code that you have in the question, you probably want the first two characters of the string. Assuming this to be the case, then the code that you want is:

```
ccode = actnum.substring(0,2);
```

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) for substring states that it returns the characters from the index specified by first argument up till, but not including, the index specified by the second argument.

The first two characters of the string would be actnum.substring(0,2). The first argument is 0-based. The second argument is also 0-based, but is not included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to have some example values...
but I suspect the problem is that you are only getting the second character of the String using
`substring(1, 2)`
the first parameter is the starting index (inclusive), the second the ending index (exclusive).

If you want the first and second character, you should use `substring(0, 2)`.

It's worth consulting the documentation: [String.substring](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))